# .draggable().resizable() don't work on a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I'm trying to make a draggable **and** resizable button with jQuery UI, but it seems that it can't do both.

```
$('.demo').resizable({grid: 10});
$('.demo').draggable({cancel:false, grid: [ 10,10 ] });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nagwW/5/)'s my code.

Is this a  jquery ui bug?

EDIT:

I've missed a `</button>`

Here's my edited version: http://jsfiddle.net/nagwW/13/

Is there a way to make the resize arrow more closer to the button?

Comment: lol, awesomely bad use of jsFiddle, :P, otherwise i'm looking at it now, i think this is  known issue if i recll correctly but not sure, double checking my google groups info now

Comment: First thing i can tell you you're doing wrong, on your fiddle `<button class="demo">move me, resize me</div>` needs to be `<button class="demo">move me, resize me</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [this jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/nagwW/12/),  this does appear to be an issue, mainly with buttons, probably due to the fact that a wrapper is added upon .resizable() call.

Also, you can turn any element into  button with a .click value, so why not just use a div, which can use both .resize and .drag with 0 problems and then use .button on that div, along with .click.

If you notice, my fiddle does exactly that

> updated fiddle with your new stuff and my div representation as well
>   http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/nagwW/25/

Although, now that i think about it, you're better off not allowing a change on the button, think about this, the user clicks the button to drag it somewhere, the drag completes, suddenly the click action is fired and their desired drag is now all messed up! That's why jquery never intended on those features being used on buttons. Could cause way to many headaches, just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your button inside a div and make it draggable and resizable, also make your button resizable. So you will have both the effects simultaneously.